# Delete a SCCM collection from the command-line

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

When using the UI (SCCM 2012), to be able to delete a collection (let's say CollA), you need first to ensure it is not linked by any rule to another (let's say CollB, etc..) such as :

- CollB includes CollA
- CollC excludes CollA

When dealing with a lot of collections, deleting a collection can be time-consuming. For that reason, I have created a script,

- usable remotely to avoid the need to connect through RDP
- which checks that CollA has no rule left (even if that is not a problem if we want to delete CollA)
- which checks if CollA is "linked" to other collections (include or exclude rules)
- which deletes any rule found (between CollB and CollA, between CollC and CollA)

I'm stuck now for I can not find a way to delete CollA.
For authentication matters and for remote purpose, I use a lot Powershell and WMI.

```
$CollA=Get-WmiObject -computername servername -namespace root\sms\site_111 -credential $cred -query "select * from SMS_Collection where Name='Tartempion'"
$CollA.get()
```

At that point, I found a method Delete(), which when I try to use it, it gives me :

```
Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "Generic failure "
At line:1 char:1
+ $coll.delete()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

If that is the method that I should use, what are the arguments to be passed ?

**EDIT 1**

As pointed by theMadTechnician, the SCCM collection, once retrieved in $CollA, a System.Management.ManagementObject.
I should, as described in the MSDN pages, be able to use the following method :

- Delete()  > produces the error mentioned above
- Delete(DeleteOptions)    > I can not find the specs for the required options
- Delete(ManagementOperationObserver)  > I can not find the specs for the required options

To ensure I properly understood the MSDN page regarding *.Delete(), i tried (successfully) the following:

```
PS C:\> Set-WmiInstance -Class win32_environment -argument @{Name="testvar";VariableValue="testvalue";UserName="<SYSTEM>"}
PS C:\> (gwmi -class win32_environment -filter "Name='testvar'").gettype()
PS C:\> (gwmi -class win32_environment -filter "Name='testvar'").delete()
```

**EDIT 2**

The fact is that when deleting a SCCM collection through the console, the collection is not the only thing removed from the inventory : the assignments for instance, are too removed. It reminds of the CASCADE switch when dealing with MySQL or ORACLE. Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible

- without using the console
- without using the SCCM cmdlets

If it can not be done that way, I just need to be sure.

**EDIT 3**

After some maturing, I am starting to wonder if it could be a authorization matter. I mean, the account I am using with the "-credential" switch or when connecting to the server, to open a SCCM console, allows me to create/update/delete collection but, for instance, it does not allow me to delete a device. I would expect the error message to be different but who knows ?

More or less about the same matter (sorry for the digression), trying to remove a device from the commandline, I found [this](http://marco-difeo.de/2011/08/02/sccm-delete-computer-object-via-powershell-and-wmi/) and I have the same error message (see above). If it works for others and not me, could it be authorization related ?

**EDIT 4**

I requested a service account with more "privileges" than I have with my technical account.
I tested and I have the same error. I am putting aside the authorization hypothesis.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a System.Management.ManagementObject that you're working with, right? Have you checked out the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject(v=vs.110).aspx) page to see the methods and how to call them for it?

Comment: See question updated, following your lead,

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in our SCCM 2012 environment by using the following command:

```
$CollA=Get-WmiObject -computername servername -namespace root\sms\site_111 -query "select * from SMS_Collection where Name='Tartempion'"
```

Basically, take the -credential out of there.  Does it work now?

Comment: Raged, I tried, deleting the collection from the server, at which point there is no need to mention the credentials, and it does not work (see error in original post). I am guessing I can't delete a collection from the commandline, due to CASCADE operations.

Comment: I see, I am able to recreate the issue.  I created two collections.  One that is linked to another.  If I delete the collection that is being limited to first, then delete the original targeted collection it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially setup a script like so:

```
#if the delete command fails...
 if(!($?))
   {
     $limitedcollectionName = $colla.LimitedCollectionName
     $limitedcollection = Get-WmiObject -computername servername -namespace root\sms\site_111 -query "select * from SMS_Collection where Name=`'$limitedcollectionname`'"
     $limitedcollectionname.delete()
    }
```

Comment: I mislead you or I did not understand your suggestion. $CollA in my environment has not a property called LimitedCollectionName. It has a property called LimitToCollectionName, which points to a collection, which I can't and do not want to delete. I know how to "unlink" two collection, whatever the link (exclude rule, include rule, etc..). Rephrased, my question would be : how to delete from the commandline a collection which is "orphan" ?